# NoMethodError when trying to invoke helper method from Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting a `NoMethodError` when trying to access a method defined in one of my helper modules from one of my controller classes. My Rails application uses the `helper` class method with the `:all` symbol as shown below:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper :all
  .
  .
end
```

My understanding is that this should make all of my controller classes automatically include all of the helper modules within the app/helpers directory, therefore mixing in all of the methods into the controllers. Is this correct?

If I explicitly `include` the helper module within the controller then everything works correctly.

Comment: Is the controller in question inheriting from ApplicationController?

Comment: Yes. I get the problem in two controllers that use the method in question and both controller inherit from ApplicationController.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`helper :all` makes all the helpers (yes, all of them) available in the views, it does not include them into the controller.

If you wish to share some code between helper and controller, which is not very desirable because helper is UI code and controller is, well, controller code, you can either include the helper in the controller, or create a separate module and include that in the controller and the helper as well.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I have some code that I want to share between two controllers. I'll create a new module and include that.

Comment: That's the best approach indeed

Comment: Is it really about sharing between two controllers? Or between controller and view? I think the latter. So gamecreature's way (@template, view_context) looks correct to me.

Comment: My funky redirect methods are in helpers. I need them from my controllers. I don't think this is bad.

Comment: You say it's undesirable to include helper methods in the controller because UI code and controller code should be separate. But what if you are doing filtering and you obviously need to access the params hash in the controller and view and sometimes you need to call methods in the view and controller to access params variables. So what would you do in that circumstance?

Answer (score 133):

To use the helper methods already included in the template engine:

- Rails 2: use the `@template` variable.
- Rails 3: has the nice controller method [`view_context`](http://apidock.com/rails/AbstractController/Rendering/view_context)

Example usage of calling 'number_to_currency' in a controller method:

```
# rails 3 sample
def controller_action
  @price = view_context.number_to_currency( 42.0 ) 
end

# rails 2 sample
def controller_action
  @price = @template.number_to_currency( 42.0 ) 
end
```

Comment: This is the best answer of the bunch - should be at the top

Comment: For Rails 3. THIS IS THE ANSWER.

Comment: No explanation for how to use `view_context`.

Comment: Another solution (works in both rails versions) is to use:  ApplicationController.helpers.number_to_currency( 42.0)

Answer (score 31):

if you need to share a method between a controller and helper/view, you can just define via 'helper_method' in the top of the controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper_method :my_shared_method
  ...

  def my_shared_method
    #do stuff
  end
end
```

hope that helps

Comment: The line `helper_method :my_shared_method` does *not* need to be at "the top".. it can go anywhere, and I like it best immediately above the definition (`def my_shared_method`).

Answer (score 29):

### Helper Methods from Controllers

One way to get at your helper methods is simply to include your helper file.

```
include LoginHelper
cool_login_helper_method(x,y,z)
```

This brings all the methods from that helper module into scope in your controller.  That's not always a good thing.  To keep the scope separate, create an object, imbue it with the powers of that helper, and use it to call the methods:

```
login_helper = Object.new.extend(LoginHelper)
login_helper.cool_login_helper_method(x,y,z)
```

---

### Helper :all

`helper :all` makes all of your helper methods from all of your helper modules available to all of your **views**, but it does nothing for your controllers.  This is because helper methods are designed for use in views and generally shouldn't be accessed from controllers.  *In newer versions of Rails, this option is always on for every controller by default.*

Answer (score 7):

For Rails 3, use the `view_context` method in your controller:

```
def foo
  view_context.helper_method
  ...
```

Here's an example: http://www.christopherirish.com/2011/10/13/no-view_context-in-rails-3-1-changes/

Answer (score 5):

The time when I find this to be most needed is for writing the flash, or custom error checkers.  Its nice to use things like link_to helpers in the flash message under some circumstances.  I use the following solution to get ActionView helpers into the controller.  Be advised that as was mentioned above, this breaks the MVC separation, so if anyone else has a better idea, let me know!

Below ApplicationController add this:

```
class Something
  include Singleton
  include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper
end
```

and inside the ApplicationController, add

```
def foo
  Something.instance
end
```

and finally, in the controller where you want to access the helper code:

```
messages << "<li class='error'>Your have an Error!<%= foo.link_to('Fix This', some_path) %></li>"
```

Hope that helps in some way!

Answer (score 5):

It is probably cleaner to use the [helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers/ClassMethods.html#method-i-helpers) method:

```
class FooController < ActionController::Base
  def action
    self.class.helpers.helper_method arg
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Any helper can be accessed using @template variable in the controller.

> @template.my_super_helper

Answer (score 3):

Controller can't access helper methods automatically. We must include them in app controller.

module ApplicationHelper

```
 def hello_message
    "Hello World"
 end
```

end

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

```
  include ApplicationHelper

  def message
     hello_message
  end
```

end

Answer (score 2):

Helpers are to be used with templates, ie. views, not in controllers. That's why you can't access the method. If you'd like to share a method between two controllers, you'd have to define it in ApplicationController, for instance. helper :all says that any method you define in any helper file in app/helpers directory will be available to any template.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this: either to create a module or use @template variable. Check this out for more details
http://www.shanison.com/?p=305

Answer (score 1):

If you change your application_controller.rb file to this...

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  include SessionsHelper
end
```

...then all helpers will be available to all controllers.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have ApplicationHelper inside your `app/helpers` folder than you have to load it in your controller with `include ApplicationHelper`. By default Rails only load the helper module that has the same name as your controller. (e.g. ArticlesController will load ArticlesHelper). If you have many models (e.g. Articles; Posts; Categories) than you have to upload each one in you controller. [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers.html)

Helper

```
module PostsHelper
    def find_category(number)
        return 'kayak-#{number}'
    end
    def find_other_sport(number)
        "basketball" #specifying 'return' is optional in ruby
    end
end

module ApplicationHelper
    def check_this_sentence
        'hello world'
    end

end
```

Example Controller

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
    include ApplicationHelper
    include PostsHelper
    #...and so on...

  def show#rails 4.1.5
    #here I'm using the helper from PostsHelper to use in a Breadcrumb for the view
    add_breadcrumb find_other_sport(@articles.type_activite), articles_path, :title => "Back to the Index"
    #add_breadcrumb is from a gem ... 
    respond_with(@articles)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try `include SessionsHelper` in ApplicationController

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include SessionsHelper
  ...
end
```