# "undefined method" when calling helper method from controller in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper, applicationcontroller

Does anyone know why I get

```
undefined method `my_method' for #<MyController:0x1043a7410>
```

when I call my_method("string") from within my ApplicationController subclass? My controller looks like

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @value = my_method(params[:string])
  end
end
```

and my helper

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def my_method(string)
    return string
  end
end
```

and finally, ApplicationController

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  after_filter :set_content_type
  helper :all
  helper_method :current_user_session, :current_user
  filter_parameter_logging :password
  protect_from_forgery # See ActionController::RequestForgeryProtection for details
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [NoMethodError when trying to invoke helper method from Rails controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453762/nomethoderror-when-trying-to-invoke-helper-method-from-rails-controller)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You cannot call helpers from controllers. Your best bet is to create the method in `ApplicationController` if it needs to be used in multiple controllers.

**EDIT**: to be clear, I think a lot of the confusion (correct me if I'm wrong) stems from the `helper :all` call. `helper :all` really just includes all of your helpers for use under any controller on the view side. In much earlier versions of Rails, the namespacing of the helpers determined which controllers' views could use the helpers.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Good information. I actually ended creating a module for my method, as promoted in the following thread, since the method is pretty generic (it converts a string to be url safe) and shouldn't be specific to controllers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128450/best-practices-for-reusing-code-between-controllers-in-ruby-on-rails/130821#130821

Comment: This is a good answer, but I would expand on it a bit further. helper_method when used in the Controller adds a method that exist _in the controller_ to the corresponding helper. i.e. method in Application Controller gets added to ApplicationHelper. This doesn't work the other way.

Answer (score 34):

view_context is your friend, http://apidock.com/rails/AbstractController/Rendering/view_context

if you wanna share methods between controller and view you have further options:

- use view_context
- define it in the controller and make available in view by the helper_method class method http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Helpers/ClassMethods/helper_method
- define it in a shared module and include/extend

Comment: Defining the methods in a shared module is a good way to go...since helpers are automatically included in Rails views.

Comment: It should be marked has the correct answer because this bring the solution to the problem. But a little explanation like @theIV did could also help. :-)

Answer (score 30):

Include ApplicationHelper in application_controller.rb file like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery       
  include ApplicationHelper  
end
```

This way all the methods defined in application_helper.rb file will be available in the controller.

You can also include individual helpers in individual controllers.

Comment: Wow, this is working if some one wants to use ApplicationHelper method in other controllers or view just add this `include ApplicationHelper `.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe I'm wrong, but aren't the helpers just for views? Usually if you need a function in a controller, you put it into ApplicationController as every function there is available in its childclasses.

Comment: Hm, that sucks. I wish I could use methods in both controllers and views. Oh well.

Comment: You can, kind of... Your `helper_method` call is giving you access to those methods in your views.

Comment: I have a helper that have to be used in the view and in the controller when rendering json with recursive tree, and I can't use it in controller?

Answer (score 6):

As said by [gamecreature](https://stackoverflow.com/users/528505/gamecreature) in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4339188):

- In Rails 2 use the `@template` variable.
- In Rails 3 use the controller method `view_context`

Answer (score 4):

helpers are for views, but adding a line of code to include that helper file in ApplicationController.rb can take care of your problem. in your case, insert the following line in ApplicationController.rb:

```
include ApplicationHelper
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as i know, `helper :all` makes the helpers available in the views...

Answer (score 3):

Try appending `module_function(*instance_methods)` in your helper modules, after which you could directly call those methods on the module itself.

Answer (score 1):

though its not a good practice to call helpers in controller since helpers are meant to be used at views 
the best way to use the helpers in controller is to make a helper method in application_controller and call them to the controller,

but even if it is required to call the helper in a controller 
then Just include the helper in the controller

```
class ControllerName < ApplicationController
  include HelperName
  ...callback statements..
```

and call the helper methods directly to the controller

```
 module OffersHelper
  def generate_qr_code(text)
    require 'barby'
    require 'barby/barcode'
    require 'barby/barcode/qr_code'
    require 'barby/outputter/png_outputter'
    barcode = Barby::QrCode.new(text, level: :q, size: 5)
    base64_output = Base64.encode64(barcode.to_png({ xdim: 5 }))
    "data:image/png;base64,#{base64_output}"
  end
```

Controller

```
class ControllerName < ApplicationController
include OffersHelper

def new
  generate_qr_code('Example Text')
end
end
```

hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem...

you can hack/bodge around it, put that logic into a model, or make a class specially for it. Models are accessible to controllers, unlike those pesky helper methods.

Here is my "rag.rb" model

```
class Rag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :report
  def miaow()
    cat = "catattack"
  end  
end
```

Here is part of my "rags_controller.rb" controller

```
def update
  @rag = Rag.find(params[:id])
  puts @rag.miaow()
  ...
```

This gave a catattack on the terminal, after I clicked "update".

Given an instantiation, methods in the model can be called. Replace catattack with some codes. (This is the best I have so far)

:helper all only opens helpers up to views.

This shows how to make a class and call it.
http://railscasts.com/episodes/101-refactoring-out-helper-object?autoplay=true

Answer (score 0):

Try this to access helper function directly from your controllers `view_context.helper_name`

Answer (score 0):

You can include your helper methods into a controller with a `helper` keyword syntax

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  helper ApplicationHelper

end
```