# Rails test/unit testing helper method, NoMethodError: undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module, helper, testunit

How to avoid this error:

```
Error: test_update_location(LocationControllerTest)
NoMethodError: undefined method `show_previous_version' for test_update_location(LocationControllerTest):LocationControllerTest/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/actionpack-2.1.1/lib/action_controller/test_process.rb:467:in `method_missing'
```

I want to test the helper method `show_previous_version` defined in `app/helpers/description_helper.rb`:

```
def show_previous_version(obj)
    ...
  return html
end
```

In `app/helpers/application _helper.rb`:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  .....
  require_dependency 'description_helper'
  ...
end
```

In `test/functional/location_controller_test.rb`

```
def test_update_location
  ...
  loc = Location.find(loc.id)
  html = show_previous_version(loc)
  ...
end
```

When I run the tests, I get:

```
Error: test_update_location(LocationControllerTest)
NoMethodError: undefined method `show_previous_version' for test_update_location(LocationControllerTest):LocationControllerTest/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/actionpack-2.1.1/lib/action_controller/test_process.rb:467:in `method_missing'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Helper methods are available to the controller instance, not on the test itself.  Either include the helper directly in the test (messy), or use the controller (or some other object that includes the helper) to call that method.

To test using the controller, you can use the @controller instance variable inside an `ActionController::TestCase`:

```
class LocationControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  def test_update_location
    ...
    loc = Location.find(loc.id)
    html = @controller.show_previous_version(loc)
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Much thank for the information about helper methods being unavailable directly in the test.  To follow up on your suggestion, can you give a simple example of using a controller -- in a test -- to call a controller helper method?

Comment: Helper methods are NOT available to the controller instance by default.

Comment: @Speakus ApplicationHelper is included by default in Rails 3, so I'm not sure what point you are making.

Comment: @PinnyM here about controller and helper: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2388943/751932