# Calling helper method from Rails 3 controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller, helper

Is it possible to call helper methods from controller? If yes how to do this in Rails 3?

Comment: Yes it is possible. You can find answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453762/nomethoderror-when-trying-to-invoke-helper-method-from-rails-controller

Comment: Please mark " view_context.some_helper_method" as answer thank you.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
 view_context.some_helper_method
```

Answer (score 30):

You can either include the helper module in the controller, or define the helper as a controller method and mark it as a helper via `helper_method :method_name`.

```
class FooHelper
  def bar ... end
end

class QuxsController
  include FooHelper
end
```

or

```
class QuxsController
  private
  def bar ... end
  helper_method :bar
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This is working if some one wants to use ApplicationHelper method in other controllers or view just add this `include ApplicationHelper` give below because all your controller derived from ApplicationController.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery       
  include ApplicationHelper  
end
```