# Using an object in a different controller in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using Rails 3, mac os  mountain lion and Ruby 1.9.3

So i have this object called object1. I built a search function for it and it works properly:

```
def self.search(search)
  search_condition = "%" + search + "%"
  if search
    find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', search_condition])
  else
    find(:all)
  end
end
```

Now I want to use this in object2. So in object2 controller I wrote:

```
def search
  @results = Object1.search(params[:search])
end
```

and in the view:

```
= form_tag object2_path, :method => 'get' do
  #{text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :id => 'search_field'}
  #{submit_tag "Search", :name => nil}

- for result in @results
  %li
    = result.name
```

But for some reason the @results return nil. What's wrong with what I'm doing? Thanks a lot.

Comment: `scope :search, ->(name) { where("name LIKE ?", name) }`

Comment: `@results` is declared in the search action, is this the action that processed the request?  if your view is not rendered after processing the search action, you'll have `@results` variable to use in the view.

Answer (score 0):

Your code to do the search is correct, that is not the problem. In your view you write:

```
= form_tag object2_path, :method => 'get' do
```

Unless you took special measure, this will hit the `index` method of your object2-controller. So you could fix this by changing your index method to search if there is a `params[:search]` defined.

Or change the path of the form to go to the search-path and make sure it renders the correct view.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure the search method is defined in routes.rb?
If you didn't it will default to the show action, and there @search is probably not set.

You also might want to change the URL of the form:

```
form_tag object2_path, :method => 'get' do
```

to

```
form_tag search_object2_path, :method => 'get' do
```

Your controller codes looks fine to me.

Answer (score -1):

Always put the common code in application helper;

**Application helper:**

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def search(search)
    search_condition = "%" + search + "%"
      if search
        find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', search_condition])
      else
        find(:all)
      end
  end
end
```

Now you can call the method from your controllers like:

```
search(params[:search])
```

If you want to make sure how you can call helper methods from controllers check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908901/calling-helper-method-from-rails-3-controller) SO post.

Comment: Helpers are intended for view code. This belongs in the model. 

Source: Pretty much everything ever written about Rails helpers.

Comment: This belongs to controller actually. I already updated according to the question. You can't say that they are intended for views only.

Comment: I agree with Fareesh.  Given this particular function, i say this belongs to the model and not a helper.  helpers are supposed to work with the view and not connect to the database.

Comment: @jvnill- In contrast to the question only, I updated the post by calling the method in a controller as the questioner is calling from there. Otherwise before that, I have kept it in a model.

Comment: Aaarrrgghh this is the worst suggestion ever. `ApplicationHelper` is for view-helpers. In this case the `search` method already is defined where it belongs: on the model. Why propose to move it to a helper? It WILL NOT WORK! The method `find` is not defined in the helper context. It only works on a ActiveRecord model.

Comment: No, the purpose to define it in a helper is because this method is called multiple times by many objects. So it should belong to a common place to increase the re-usability.