# Helper not defining methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Ruby on Rails 3.2

My sessions_controller.rb checks for 'signed_in_person' to bypass login if they already have a logged session.

My 'signed_in_person' is defined in the session_helper.rb but I get an error:

```
Started POST "/sessions" for 50.241.102.227 at 2014-02-25 10:12:33 -0800
Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"fFo4EM1MOHNO1Thic6qA/uapGj8pbiNaepKYF5Ge0Tw=", "session"=>{"email"=>"dduck@blah.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "com
mit"=>"Sign in"}
Person Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `persons`.* FROM `persons` WHERE `persons`.`email` = 'dduck@blah.com' LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 66ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `sign_in_person' for #<SessionsController:0x00000004f7ace8>):
app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:11:in `create'
```

The Person is in the database table when checked from console.
My sessions_controller:

```
def create
    if params[:session][:email].include? 'blah.com'
        person = Person.find_by_email(params[:session][:email].downcase)
        if person && person.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
            sign_in_person person
            redirect_back_or person
        else
            flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
            render 'new'
        end
    else
        ...
    end
end
```

My sessions_helper:

```
module SessionsHelper

# For Persons

def sign_in_person(person)
    cookies[:remember_token] = person.remember_token
    self.current_person = person
end

def signed_in_person?
    !current_person.nil?
end
    ...
```

Any ideas as to why my sessions_helper isn't helping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Helper methods are available from the views, not from the Controller.

To use them from the Controller, (Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908901/calling-helper-method-from-rails-3-controller)) you can either:

1. include the helper module in the controller
2. define the helper as a controller method and mark it as a helper via `helper_method :method_name`.

In your case, since you'll be using several methods from `SessionsHelper` I think it would be best include the helper like this:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  include SessionsHelper


  ...
end
```

Comment: This did not change the error, :( If I add, 'include SessionsHelper' to my persons_controller the error went away. Is that okay?

Comment: @DDDD It's really weird, since the error log says you tried to call `sign_in_person` from `SessionsController`... did you used the method on `PersonsController` too?

Comment: No but the PersonsController is what is using the SessionsController

Answer (score 1):

This is generally bad practice, but you could use `view_context.sign_in_person` from your controller. I believe you can also use the `helper` method in your controller, something like this:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  helper :sessions

  ...
end
```

Helpers are generally supposed to be for views. Like raviolicode said, you can move it to the controller and use `helper_method` to make it accessible to both your controller and view.

```
# in controller
def sign_in_person
  ....
end
helper_method :sign_in_person
```

If you only want it available from your controller, it's probably best to just make a private method inside of the controller itself, or move it into a [concern](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to invoke a helper method from within a controller, you'll need to call it according to whether or not it is a class or instance method on the helper:

```
# app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  include SessionsHelper

  def create
    person = Person.find_by_email(params[:session][:email].downcase)
    SessionsHelper.sign_in_person person # Class method invocation
    sign_in_person person # Instance method invocation
  end

end

# app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb
module SessionsHelper

  # Instance method
  def sign_in_person(person)
    cookies[:remember_token] = person.remember_token
    SessionHelper.current_person = person
  end

  # Class method
  def self.sign_in_person(person)
    cookies[:remember_token] = person.remember_token
    self.current_person = person
  end

end
```