# Helper method not exposed to controller Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here's the code:

```
class SyncController < ApplicationController
  def get_sync
    @passed_ids = params[:ids].split(',')
    @users = @passed_ids.collect{|id| User.find(id)}

    #add the current user to the list
    @users << current_user
    @recommendations = get_recommendations(@users)
  end
end

module SyncHelper
  def get_recommendations(users)
    users
  end
end
```

I'm getting a can't find `get_recommendations` method error...

Comment: i think you'll find your answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453762/nomethoderror-when-trying-to-invoke-helper-method-from-rails-controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `SyncHelper` module needs to be included into your `SyncController` class. You can either add the line

```
include SyncHelper
```

in your class definition, or, if `SyncHelper` lives in the expected app/helpers file, you can use the rails [helper](http://apidock.com/rails/AbstractController/Helpers/ClassMethods/helper) method.